# Кнопка Like instagram

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

Как добавить виджет на сайт кнопки "Like" Instagram? Аналогичные есть в ВК, FB Google+ с количеством лайков.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого возможности нет. Кнокп Вк делает действие, которое отображается у вас на стене. В инстаграме такой возможности нет. Однако вы можете установить кнопку Follow на подобии кнопки Подписаться ВК. Она позволяет одним нажатием подписатьсч на ваш аккаунт

HTML:

```
<span class="ig-follow" data-id="5479dee" data-handle="igfbdotcom" data-count="true" data-size="large" data-username="true"></span>
```

JS:

```
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src="//x.instagramfollowbutton.com/follow.js";s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);}(document,"script"));
```

Делается это с помощью стороннего сервиса, например, InstaFollowButton.